# EPPlus Hyperlink to cell in another sheet

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, epplus-4

i'm struggling with adding hyperlinks to another list to my generated excel file. I tried it like this:

```
ws.Cells[1, 1].Formula="HYPERLINK(\"[#]'sheetName'!R4C1\";\"linktext\")"
ws.Cells[1, 1].Formula="HYPERLINK(\"#'sheetName'!R4C1\";\"linktext\")"
ws.Cells[1, 1].FormulaR1C1="HYPERLINK(\"[#]'sheetName'!R4C1\";\"linktext\")"
ws.Cells[1, 1].FormulaR1C1="HYPERLINK(\"#'sheetName'!R4C1\";\"linktext\")"
```

After opening generated excel file in excel 365 (full offline application) i just get message that there are errors in the file and all the cells where I used this hyperlink formula are empty.

The error message is:

```
we found a problem with some content in FILENAME do you want us to try to recover as much as we can
```

How to make it work?

Also when i put same formula in cell manually it works.

Complete code:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExcelHyperlinkTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MemoryStream excelStream = new MemoryStream();
            ExcelPackage excelFile = new ExcelPackage(excelStream);

            ExcelWorksheet wsSrc = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("src");
            ExcelWorksheet wsTgt = excelFile.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("tgt");

            wsSrc.Cells[1, 1].Formula = string.Format("HYPERLINK(\"#'{0}'!R{1}C{2}\";\"{3}\")", "tgt", 2, 5, "test"); //FormulaR1C1

            excelFile.Save();
            excelStream.Position = 0;

            using (FileStream file = new FileStream("c:\\linkTest.xlsx", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[excelStream.Length];
                excelStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)excelStream.Length);
                file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                excelStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This works

```
wsSrc.Cells[1, 6].Value = "test3";
            Uri url = new Uri("#'tgt'!B5", UriKind.Relative);
            wsSrc.Cells[1, 6].Hyperlink = url;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the sheet exist in the same excel file and any one using EPPlus library, then following code might help them:

```
int rowCount=<your specific row> 
ws.Cells[rowCount, 6].Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink((char)39 + "Name of your sheet" + 
(char)39 + "!A1(specific cell on that sheet)", "Link text");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will link to B5 in the sheet (sheetName) in a workbook (workbookPath) , relative to the current workbook and formats the link as a hyperlink

```
using (ExcelRange rng = xlsheetSummary.Cells[1, 1])
{
    var namedStyle = xlsheetSummary.Workbook.Styles.NamedStyles.FirstOrDefault(o=> o.Name == "HyperLink");

    namedStyle.Style.Font.UnderLine = true;
    rng.StyleName = namedStyle.Name;

    rng.Value = ws.Name;
    Uri link = new Uri($"{workbookPath}#'{sheetName}'!B5", UriKind.Relative);
    namedStyle.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Blue);                                 
    rng.Hyperlink = link;
}
```